Problems with the materials when trying to export as FBX mesh
I am a newbie in Blender, and this is the first time I have used UV unwrapping and texture painting. I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1CFWDWTamo
for most of the characters, I've used simple materials by changing colors, and for the head some texture painting (for the eyes).
The issue I am facing is when I export the project. Only the texture painting is exported with the mesh but not the materials.
I tried everything I could find on the Internet but with no result.
Here is the project in blender : 
Here is the project when exported as FBX : 
PS: I've tried to pack the resources; I've exported the FBX file with the texture + the selected objects
Here is my blend file : 

Is it the same discussion here? https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons/issues/96538

none of this fixed my problem

The problem is the dot/period (.) in the names of the images.
In Blender, object names must be unique. When you duplicate an object (mesh, bone, image, etc.), Blender adds a dot with an ascending number such as .001 to the name of the copied object to ensure that it's unique.
If you check your images in the Image Editor you will see that you have:

Untitled (that's OK)
Untitled.001 (problematic)
Untitled.002 (disturbing!)
Untitled.003 (troublesome!!)
Untitled.004 (just bad!! ;-)


Those with the dots are bad because when the model is exported the images are saved in files like Untitled.001.png. The "double" file extension is causing the problem and the loading of the images fails when you import the model again. (This should not happen. It might be a bug or an oversight.)
Fix: Simply give the images real names without a dot in the name or with the right file extension (*.png, *.jpg, etc). Something like jacket or jacket.png
While we're on the subject, a few more problems to fix:

the material CHDA D SABRE has an Image Texture node but no selected image. Select one.
the mesh of the model has duplicated vertices. To remove them, select all vertices in Edit mode and M > Merge them By Distance.


thanks a looot for taking time to check my blend file , ill be fixing these issue and be back with an answer
